# Migrating forked project from Heroku to Github

Tags: heroku, github

Some time ago I found some code in one Github repo. I downloaded it (did not fork it), started upgrading it and when I was happy with the result, I used Heroku as a host. So now the code lives on my computer and Heroku. How could I push it to my Github account, but also give the original author of the project some credit for it (showing on my Github that I actually forked it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I actually figured it out already!

First, create a new repository on github, let's name it **github-project**.

```
git clone git@heroku.com:<heroku-project>.git
cd <heroku-project>
git remote rm origin
git remote add github https://github.com/<github-username>/<github-project>
git pull github master
```

Now you'll probably see some conflicts. If you want to preserve all your changes, just add them all.

```
git add .
git commit -m "some message"
git push github master
```

Comment: This is more complicated than it needs to be, due to the unnecessary `git pull github master`. See my answer for a cleaner solution with no conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple:

1. Create an **empty** repository on GitHub, let's call it `github-project`
2. Clone from Heroku, let's call it `heroku-project`
3. Add a remote for github
4. Push to GitHub

The commands to perform these steps:

```
git clone git@heroku.com:heroku-project.git
cd heroku-project
git remote add github https://github.com/github-username/github-project
git push -u github master
```

That's it!

Note: if you already created the GitHub project with a README file in it, then it is NOT empty anymore, and the last push will be refused. In that case you can force the push, effectively overwriting the project on GitHub, by using the `--force` flag, for example:

```
git push -u github master --force
```